# Can't insert ñ character to an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, encoding

I've got an issue inserting ñ chatacter to an Oracle database.

The INSERT operation completes successfully. 
However, when I SELECT, I get n instead of ñ.

Also, I noticed executing:

```
select 'ñ' from dual;
```

gives me 'n'.

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

gives me 'EE8MSWIN1250'.

How do I insert ñ?
I'd like to avoid modifying db settings.

---

The only way I got this working was:

1. read the input .csv file with its windows-1250 encoding
2. change encoding to unicode
3. change strings to unicode codes representation (in which ñ is \00d1)
4. execute INSERT/UPDATE passing the value from #3 to a UNISTR function

For sure there is an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be, find out the `ASCII` of the character using `ASCII()` and insert use `CHR()` to convert back to string.

**SQL:**

```
select ascii('ñ'),chr(50097) from dual;
```

**Output:**

```
ASCII('Ñ') CHR(50097)
---------- ----------
     50097 ñ
```

The client you are using to connect to database matters. Some clients, donot support these characters.

Answer (score 2):

Before you start your SQL*Plus you have to set the codepage (using `chcp` command) and `NLS_LANG` environment parameter accordingly:

```
chcp 1250
set NLS_LANG=.EE8MSWIN1250
sqlplus ...
```

However as already given in comments, Windows 1250 does not support character `ñ`. So, these values will not work.

It is not compulsory to set these values equal to your database character set, however codepage and `NLS_LANG` must match, i.e. following ones should work as well (as they all support `ñ`)

```
chcp 1252
set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
sqlplus ...
```

or to support any character as UTF-8

```
chcp 65001
set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
sqlplus ...
```

Again, EE8MSWIN1250 does not support character `ñ`, unless data type of your column is `NVARCHAR2` (resp. `NCLOB`) it is not possible to store `ñ` in the database.

Comment: column type is NVARCHAR2

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Anyway `.EE8MSWIN1250`, resp `chcp 1252` does not work - not due to database limits but your SQL*Plus won't be able to send such characters to database with these settings.

Comment: Since you use dbForge as client `chcp ...` is most likely not valid for you. Check encoding settings in your dbForge client. However, setting environment variable `NLS_LANG` properly is still required.

Answer (score 1):

Is that character supported by the database character set?
I could not find that character here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250

I had no problems inserting that character in my database which has character set WE8MSWIN1252.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252

Comment: Even though the db character set is EE8MSWIN1250, I can see some ñ-s in the database. The problem is, I can't figure out how to insert ñ myself. It always gets translated to n.

Comment: Check the byte value of the charaters you find in the database and the one you want to insert. example: select 'ñ',dump('ñ') from dual; The dump function will give you the value. In my case 241.

Comment: Typ=96 Len=1: 110

Comment: And what value do you get for the ñ character already in the database? Then use Maheswaran Ravisankar answer to write that value in your new record.

Comment: It's 324 and chr(324) returns 'D'.

Comment: 324 is an odd value for the WIN1250 character set. What is the data_type of the column you are querying? select data_type
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
   and column_name = 'YOUR_COLUMN'

Comment: Rene - it's NVARCHAR2. It appears the problem is with the client I use (dbForge).